# How to search a word in doctrine ORM?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

I would like to know if this is possible in doctrine ORM symfony.
I have a list of Products. Each product has a Title.
let say their titles are:

```
1. Great Mango
2. Show Mango
3. King Mango
```

I use this doctrine to find the title

```
$repository->findByTitle("Mango");
```

but I display nothing. If I complete the title to search it like "King Mango". It display but not the list with the MANGO word.

I used this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) for reference. but if you have more documentation about this. I'm happy to learn from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic methods only work with exact search. To use a `LIKE` statement, you'll have to create your own repository, as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html

Once you have your own repository class, create a method that uses `LIKE` in the query:

```
public function findByTitlePart($title)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Product p WHERE p.title LIKE :title'
        )
        ->setParameter('title', '%' . $title . '%')
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To use a `like` in the where clause, you have to use `where` condition with `setParameter`.
query as below:

```
$title = 'Mango';
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
           ->where('a.title LIKE :title')
           ->setParameter('title', '%'.$title.'%')
           ->getQuery();
```